# Extracting AD records attributes from a group but need manager's email address as well

Tags: powershell

I have this script that gets all the members from a security group and then extracts to a file a bunch of their attributes.   It works correctly except to pull the manager's email address.   The weird thing is though if I run this command to get the manager's email address directly in PowerShell it does return their email address.

Here is the entire script:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "ACP Users" -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Property employeeNumber, SN, Manager, GivenName, Name, Office,
        Mobile, emailaddress, Department, Title, 
        samaccountname, officephone, homephone |
    select employeeNumber,SN, GivenName,Manager, Office, Mobile, 
        emailaddress,Department, Title, samaccountname, 
        officephone,homephone,enabled | 
    Select-object @{Name='Empno';Expression={$_."employeeNumber"}},
        @{Name='EmployeeName';Expression={$_."GivenName" + ' ' + $_."SN"}},
        @{N='Manager';E={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name}},
        @{N='ManagerSAM';E={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).samaccountname}},
        @{N='ManagerEmail';E={(Get-ADUser(Get-ADUser $._samaccountname -Properties manager).manager -properties mail).mail}},
        @{Name='EmployeeEmail';Expression={$_."emailAddress"}},
        @{Name='Office';Expression={$_."Office"}},
        @{Name='Title';Expression={$_."Title"}},
        @{Name='Department';Expression={$_."Department"}},
        enabled |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\ACP_Uers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

IF I run this part manually in PowerShell it returns an Active Directory user record manually it works just fine:

```
(Get-ADUser(Get-ADUser chuck.east -Properties manager).manager -Properties mail).mail
```

File output when ran as the whole script, you can see the email is blank for the manager but it was able to get the manager and manager's sam.

```
"Empno","EmployeeName","Manager","ManagerSAM","ManagerEmail","EmployeeEmail","Office","Title","Department","enabled"
"8921","Chuck East","Jim Dean","jim.dean",,"Chuck.East@sb.com","East","BSA","IT","True"
```

Any idea as to why it's not pulling the manager's email?

Comment: I applaud the use of calculated properties however since you are calling the same user multiple times to get different properties it would be more efficient do this with a foreach loop. That way you can load up the individual properties easier and send them down the pipe using `[pscustomobject]@{}`

Comment: HI Matt,  Are you talking about where I am getting manager properties multiple times? I'm interested in what you are saying but not sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@{N='ManagerEmail';E={
    (Get-ADUser(
        Get-ADUser $._samaccountname - Properties manager).manager -properties mail).mail
    }
},
```

You have a typo, `$._samaccountname` I think. Should be `$_.samaccountname`

I'm not sure why you departed from the earlier pattern. This should work:

```
@{N='ManagerEmail';E={
        Get-ADUser $_.manager -properties mail).mail
    }
},
```

Of course, you could get the manager object once instead of three times... And per Matt's suggestion, build the object instead of using Select-Object, something like this: (untested... On my phone)

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity “ACP Users” -Recursive | get-aduser -Property employeeNumber,SN, Manager, GivenName, Name,Office, Mobile, emailaddress,Department, Title, samaccountname,officephone,homephone | Foreach-Object {
    $manager = Get-ADUser $_ -Properties email
    $outputData = [ordered] @{
            Empno=$_."employeeNumber"
            EmployeeName=$_."GivenName" + ' ' + $_."SN"
            Manager=$manager.distinguishedName
            #etc for the other properties you want
    }
    New-object psobject -properties $outputData
} | Export-csv -path C:\temp\ACP_Uers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Veefu,  Thank you for that spot on the TYPO!      How would I accomplish the same and only get the manager object once getting all the three manager properties and assigning them to the three variables?

Comment: On my phone so editing is a bit rough... But open a new block with Foreach-Object, then `$manager = get-aduser $_.manager -properties name, smamaccountname, email` then pipe `$_`  to your existing `Select-Object` expression, replacing all the `get-aduser $_.manager` business with `$manager.name` etc.

Comment: Updated answer with a bit of an example. Goes well with suggestion from @matt